# Why are bugs treated differently in the TFS agile and scrum templates

Tags: tfs, scrum

One of the key differences between the MSF for Agile template and the Visual Studio Scrum template is that Scrum

> manages bugs along with product backlog items during sprint planning

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms400752(v=vs.110).aspx

The Scrum approach makes sense to me. Fixing a bug involves planned work and creates some sort of benefit for end users.

Why are bugs not managed as backlog items using the agile template? 
Is the team expected to just absorb time spend fixing bugs? 
Is the template assuming another resource will attend to bugs outside of the project scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expected workflow in the Agile template, is that a Bug WI will be created, then a linked User Story to represent the work to fix that bug.  The User Story is what goes on the backlog and is prioritized.

If you inspect the Bug WITD XML you will see that in the transition from Active to Resolved one of the Reasons is "Copied To Backlog", this is meant to indicate a related User Story was created.

It's really awkward, but that's how the template was originally designed for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

Because the Agile template is not intended to support Agile work. It is an agile implementation of the Microsoft Solution Framework (MSF) designed by Microsoft Consulting Services (MCS) for working with client engagements.

The only template that supports an agile workflow out of the box is the Scrum template.

http://nakedalm.com/agile-vs-scrum-process-templates-team-foundation-server/